# Package.json: Set "version" property from another file

Tags: javascript, json, package.json

is it possible, to set the "version" property in the package.json through another (js || json) File?

Something like this:

```
import {AppVersion} from "./index";
{
  "name": "test_app",
  "version": AppVersion,
}
```

Comment: It will get you into trouble if you succeed in this - I would recommend that you instead either use package.json to get the version to use in another file, or (if you want to set the same version for different package.json files to increment a version in sync), you use a build step with `npm version 1.2.3` or something similar if you are not using npm.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any tutorial (which doesn't say much as I'm not deep into npm usage), but the official docs at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-version are quite extensive - if you want to know more about semantic versioning (semver) too, you'll find a link there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The [`package.json` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file) must be a JSON file, not a JS file, and cannot use `import` syntax.